# Checking if sampling points located on a mineral grain are homogeneous

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Is there a way to determine if all the observations made over a population are similar?
The data consists of 14 variables and 10-15 observation points over a mineral grain. Some cells have null value. I have to check if that mineral grain is homogeneous and if not to what degree.

Comment: You can start by trying some clustering (k-means with k= the number of grains you got). If you see serious deviations, consider using some per-grain multiple comparisons methods.

Comment: I’ve got data on 4 mineral grains. I’d like to know what these per grain comparison methods could be.

Answer (score 0):

These methods belong to the multiple comparisons area: For each grain we assume some distribution $F_i$, for each observation $j$ in grain $i$ we assume $H_{ij,0}:x_{ij}\sim F_i$. Then, for each grain your global hypothesis is that all observations come from the same distribution $F_i$. As this isn't a simple topic, I suggest you read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) to try and understand what you need to do.

Another option, which might be easier for your, is using some anomaly detection algorithms, an example could be found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/anomaly-detection-in-r/).

Comment: This may be a bit too basic question but how is this Holm Bonferroni approach different from Darling Anderson test?

Comment: AD is to compare the dataset as a whole to some known disribution, while HB assumes some distribution and then check each point individually